# Extjs how to resize grid height when the window is maximized

Tags: extjs, grid, resize, window

i need to set my grid fit on the screen when the window is resized

```js
 xtype: 'grid',
 autoScroll:true,
 border: true,
 margin: '10 10 20 10',
 height: 350,
 index: '',
 width: '100%',
 name:'grd_PrintConsole',
 forceFit: true,
 columns: tempColumns
```

Comment: Width, height or both? Is grid the only child item of the window? Have you tried setting layout `fit` for the window?

Comment: The issue is at height . I tried layout : fit, but it is not working.

Comment: And the window have more child..

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) with your problem?

Comment: Damn, SORRY - it's ExtJS 4.2, not 5!